# How to draw/highlight pixels by touching the screen across a Path in Android

Tags: android

I've been trying to search what are the basic classes and methods, i should call for the task described in the title! i have been through many codes but they are not making me understand what is the basic procedure for that...

Answer (score 0):

The [FingerPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html) example is a good starting point.